# Androd, Realm: Realm.getDefaultInstance(), IllegalStateException: downloadAllServerChanges() cannot be called from the main thread

Tags: android, realm

Realm 3.5.0

In my Application class I login to Realm Object Server and after success I set Realm set default configruation.

```
public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication {
```

...

```
private void setRealmDefaultConfiguration(SyncUser syncUser, String realmURL) {
    SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(syncUser, realmURL)
            .waitForInitialRemoteData()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}
```

}

OK.

and in my fragment I try to get Realm instance.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // HERE THROW ERROR
    return rootView;
}
```

}

But I get error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: downloadAllServerChanges() cannot be called from the main thread.
    at io.realm.SyncSession.checkIfNotOnMainThread(SyncSession.java:357)
    at io.realm.SyncSession.downloadAllServerChanges(SyncSession.java:322)
    at io.realm.internal.SyncObjectServerFacade.downloadRemoteChanges(SyncObjectServerFacade.java:176)
    at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:305)
    at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:284)
    at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:281)
    at com.myproject.fragment.MyFragment.onCreateView(OrganizationsFragment.java:147)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `downloadAllServerChanges() cannot be called from the main thread.`; So create a new thread and call that function there

Answer (score 1):

`.waitForInitialRemoteData()` uses the network, so you are not allowed to call `Realm.getInstance()` on the UI thread with any configuration with that setting. It would ANR your app. This should also be documented in the Javadoc for `waitForInitialRemoteData`.

Instead, you can use `Realm.getInstanceAsync()`, it will load the data on a background thread and return the Realm instance once it is ready.

Comment: That's a bit tricky though, does that mean if you use multiple activities, then you'll need to use `Realm.getInstanceAsync()` in every place where you open a Realm (on the UI thread)? Hmmmm....

Comment: Yes, that would be the implication. Alternatively, we have `SyncSession.downloadAllServerChanges()` which can be called manually on a background thread, but then you need to coordinate with your UI if you want to be 100% sure changes are downloaded before opening anything that uses Realm.